# Asp.net Mvc: access external project Bundles

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have a project called WebLibrary, which contains lots of library controls `css` and `js` files.

To improve performance, i am compressing and combining all the css files using `Bundles`:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/allLibrary8Css", new CssMinify())
            .Include(
                "~/Controls/Common/common.css",
                "~/Controls/ApplicationTopHeader/applicationTopHeader.css",
                "~/Controls/StatusBar/statusBar.css"
                // other files
            ));
    }
}
```

This generates a compressed and minified *random* css file (or resource)

[image]

However, i want from an external project to reference to this compressed file (or resource), but i can't do it because of the random name it generates:

`/bundles/allLibrary8Css?v=VSqWZLr-gqdgDlMqOOg6ULA53tJ-5qFiIBRY6Qe-VHw1`

`http://library.myApp.com/bundles/allLibrary8Css?v=VSqWZLr-gqdgDlMqOOg6ULA53tJ-5qFiIBRY6Qe-VHw1`

Is there any way to prevent the random name created by the bundle so i can reference it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can, you can safely ignore query string, and everything will be ok, however, then you have problem with cache ...